# (geopandas) How to output longitude/latitude scale correctly in Mercator projetion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

Longitude and latitude scale next to axes are not correct in a Mercator map created with geopandas (Python3).

I made a Mercator-projecrioned map with geopandas like this.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.name != "Antarctica") & (world.name != "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands")]
world = world.to_crs("EPSG:3395")

ax = world.plot()
ax.set_title("Mercator")

plt.show()
```

The map itself was correctly output, but longitude/latitude scales next to axes were incorrect as in images below.

Mercator_map
[image]

Longitude is supposed to range -180 to 180, and latitude -90 to 90. However, scales in the image don't do so.

How could I get correctly output scales?

Comment: Please add your image directly in the post, not as a link

Comment: Looks like the coordinates in your plot are in metres, the circumference of the earth being about 4x10^7 meters. Indeed EPSG:3395 has units of metres, see https://epsg.io/3395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPSG:3395 is a mercator (cylindrical) projection with units of metres. You need a cylindrical projection in units of degrees (which is called a Plate Carree or Equidistant Cylindrical projection). Use EPSG:4326 - For example see  https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/user_guide/projections.html

More info on EPSG:4326 here: https://epsg.io/4326

More info on EPSG:3395 here: https://epsg.io/3395

Discussion of Mercator compared to Plate Carree (aka Platte Carre) https://idvux.wordpress.com/2007/06/06/mercator-vs-well-not-mercator-platte-carre/

Answer (score 1):

To draw geographic graticule (lines of meridian and parallels of latitude), and label them with values in degrees you can use `cartopy` gridlines() function. Here is the modified code and the output plot.

[cartopy.gridlines document](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.gridlines)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

myproj = ccrs.Mercator()
pcproj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7))
extent =[-179,179,  -78, 85]  #lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax
ax = plt.axes(projection=myproj )
ax.set_extent(extent, crs=pcproj)

lon_grid = np.arange(-180, 180, 30)
lat_grid = np.arange(-75, 83, 15)
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True,
                  xlocs=lon_grid, ylocs=lat_grid,
                  x_inline=False, y_inline=False,
                  color='k', linestyle='dotted')

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
antarctica = world[world.name == "Antarctica"].to_crs("EPSG:3395")  #just in case

world = world[(world.name != "Antarctica") & (world.name != "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands")]
world = world.to_crs("EPSG:3395")

ax = world.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor='k', lw=0.3)

# if you prefer to plot `Antarctica`
if True:
    antarctica.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgray')

ax.set_title("Mercator")

plt.show()
```

[image: mercator]